# Google Cloud Print opens "print to file" dialogue box on printer's home computer--and never prints

Tags: google-chrome, google-cloud-print

When I try to use Google cloud print from a computer not attached to the printer in question (from Google Drive), it opens a dialog box titled "Print to File" with the text "Output File Name:" and a text box on the printer that *is* attached to the printer in question--and never prints, regardless of whether I put a filename in the text box or not.

The attached computer runs Windows 7, and the unattached computer runs WinXP Pro with Chrome version 29.0.1547.66m.

What the what?

Comment: *Print to file* means that the result is sent to a file and **not** to the printer. If you enter a filename (e.g. `D:\myprintfile`) and print the button to 'print' then a new file should be created. Can you verify that this is the case?

Comment: AHA. Some-bizarre-how, the printer listed as the correct model of the actual printer and chosen as default transmogrified into a print-to-file fake.  Shared the correct printer with cloud print and now it works.

Comment: @Krysta , go down and submit that as an answer for anyone who find this same thing.

Answer (score 0):

As Hennes has pointed out, print to file is generally used to save the file to your local system as a file. It is used to save the webpage in your system with the specified name and location.

Select the printer in the selection menu or use the option;
Ctrl+Shift+P to get the ordinary print dialog.